# Getting 401 unauthorized status in an API

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests, configparser

I was making a POST request in nutritionix API using requests module. In one of the API route which is `https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients`, which returns all the necessary details for any food item if we pass json as `{"query": <any_name>}` and headers as `x-app-id` and `x-app-key`.

It works fine in Postman, but in Python it shows 401 unauthorized status if I fetch the x-app-id and x-app-key from .cfg file.

The format of that cfg file is

```
[nutritionix]
API_ID=<api-id>
API_KEY=<api-key>
```

I am fetching all those keys using configparser module, I am able to print those keys in the terminal, but it shows 401 error. But if I directly paste these keys into the code directly (which is not recommended), it is showing 200 status.

I am pasting the code below for reference:

```
import requests
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('./secrets.cfg')

x_app_id = config['nutritionix']['API_ID']
x_app_key = config['nutritionix']['API_KEY']

headers = {
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "x-app-id": x_app_id,
    "x-app-key": x_app_key,
}


url = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients/'

def get_details(prompt: str):
    food_details = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={"query": prompt})
    print(food_details)
```

I don't know why the API key and the ID is not fetching from cfg file, whereas in other files, it is fetching properly.

I was expecting to fetch the API keys from cfg and show the required result from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will works

```
import requests
from configparser import ConfigParser
import json

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('./secrets.cfg')

x_app_id = config['nutritionix']['API_ID']
x_app_key = config['nutritionix']['API_KEY']

headers = {
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "x-app-id": x_app_id,
    "x-app-key": x_app_key,
}


url = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients/'

def get_details(prompt: str):
    food_details = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={"query": prompt})
    print(json.dumps(food_details.json(), indent=2))

get_details('for breakfast i ate 2 eggs, bacon, and french toast')
```

And credential without " or ' in `secrets.cfg` file.

```
[nutritionix]
API_ID=xxxxxxxx
API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Result

```
$ python3 get-nutrients.py 
Status Code 200
JSON Response  {
  "foods": [
    {
      "food_name": "eggs",
      "brand_name": null,
      "serving_qty": 2,
      "serving_unit": "large",
      "serving_weight_grams": 100,
      "nf_calories": 143,
      "nf_total_fat": 9.51,
      "nf_saturated_fat": 3.13,
      "nf_cholesterol": 372,
      "nf_sodium": 142,
      "nf_total_carbohydrate": 0.72,
      "nf_dietary_fiber": 0,
      "nf_sugars": 0.37,
      "nf_protein": 12.56,
      "nf_potassium": 138,
      "nf_p": 198,
      "full_nutrients": [
        {
          "attr_id": 203,
          "value": 12.56
        },
...
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this approach worked for me, I was including the credentials in double quotes. Thanks!

Comment: I am happy to hear you got it.